# Подключение не защищено

Tags: openserver

Я пытаюсь открыть сайт локально используя Open Server, но вылезает следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я открываю OS как администратор.

Настройки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Логи:

`основной`

```
2020-09-24 14:27:39  --------------------------------------------
2020-09-24 14:27:39  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
2020-09-24 14:27:40  Обновление Hosts файла
2020-09-24 14:27:40  Обновление конфигурации MariaDB-10.3
2020-09-24 14:27:40  Обновление конфигурации Sendmail
2020-09-24 14:27:40  Обновление конфигурации PHP_7.1
2020-09-24 14:27:40  Обновление конфигурации PHPMyAdmin
2020-09-24 14:27:40  Обновление конфигурации Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1
2020-09-24 14:27:40  Запуск MariaDB-10.3
2020-09-24 14:27:40  Запуск Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1
2020-09-24 14:27:40  Проверка состояния сервера
2020-09-24 14:27:40  Cервер успешно запущен за 0,969 секунд!
```

`Apache отладка`

```
[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.824144 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH01909: test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.825144 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH01909: robotasha:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.826143 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH01909: q:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.826143 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH01909: new:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.827143 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH01909: default:443:0 server certificate     does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.948376 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH01909: test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.949376 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH01909: robotasha:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.949376 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH01909: q:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.950375 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH01909: new:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.950375 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH01909: default:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.985354 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH00455: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2s configured -- resuming normal operations

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.985354 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Aug 12 2019 10:48:01

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.985354 2020] [core:notice] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\openserver\\openserver\\modules\\http\\Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/OpenServer/OpenServer/modules/http/Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1 -f c:\\openserver\\openserver\\modules\\http\\Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1\\conf\\httpd.conf'

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:40.990351 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5704:tid 444] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9832

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:41.603266 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9832:tid 480] AH01909: test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:41.604265 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9832:tid 480] AH01909: robotasha:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:41.604265 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9832:tid 480] AH01909: q:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:41.605265 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9832:tid 480] AH01909: new:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:41.605265 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9832:tid 480] AH01909: default:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:41.733242 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9832:tid 480] AH01909: test:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:41.734242 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9832:tid 480] AH01909: robotasha:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:41.734242 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9832:tid 480] AH01909: q:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:41.735241 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9832:tid 480] AH01909: new:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Thu Sep 24 14:27:41.735241 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9832:tid 480] AH01909: default:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 24 14:27:41.778270 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9832:tid 480] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Как мне убрать эту ошибку?

Comment: Вам принципиально https соединение? Как вариант перейти на http

Comment: @BigTows мне не принципиально, поскольку это моя локальная машина. Как мне перейти на http?

Comment: Если обратиться к ресурсу по URL`http://new/` 
Будет редирект?

Comment: @BigTows да, все равно та же ошибка. Значит есть

Comment: Я к сожалению с OpenServer не сталкивался, не знаю как отключить данный редирект (Возможно хром сам редиректит, тогда можно домен попробовать поменять), но попробуйте следующие: Откройте страницу, на которой возникает данная ошибка и начните вводить `thisisunsafe`

Comment: @BigTows Спасибо. Интересный метод, тк это локальная машина вполне подходит для меня. Можете написать это как ответ и я его приму чуть позже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрю только один из вариантов, который возможен в данной ситуации:

Возможно `Google Chrome` сам производит повышения до `https`, как вариант можно сделать одно из:

1. Поменять домен с `new/`, на `new.ru`, тогда в таком случае редиректа не должно быть;
2. Можно на странице с ошибкой начать вводить `thisisunsafe`, тогда `Google Chrome`, вас пропустит :)

Comment: 1)Можно ничего не менять, а например, использовать другой браузер, у которого есть свое хранилище сертификатов, к пример FireFox, добавить сертификат в исключения и сайт будет открываться потом без вопросов.

Comment: У вас стоит самоподписный сертификат, если пересоздать сертификат с полем SAN, и добавить туда имя компа(FQDN) и IP и/или 127.0.0.1 и переходить по адресу https://127.0.0.1, то все будет работать без ошибок, если добавить этот сертификат в корневые ЦС хранилища юзера.